# Some related records not found in collections

Tags: laravel, collections

I have the following query that was working fine in laravel 5.4, however after migrating to a new server and updating to laravel 8 some of the related records are not linking in the collection and registrations->customers returns null.

The weird part is that I can create a join query and get the related result that way and a majority of records all function normally and return their related customer model data, just about 10% don't work.  I have a feeling its an issue with server setup or mysql settings but its just really weird.

```
$query = Paymentplan::query()->wherehas('orders', function($q){
    $q->where('course_id','<', '99');
});

$registrations = $query->with('orders', 'customers')->orderby('paymentplans.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(50)->appends(request()->query());
```

Paymentplan Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\CustomerPromotions;
use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

class PaymentPlan extends Model
{
    
    use RevisionableTrait;
    use Uuids;

    use RevisionableTrait, Uuids {
        Uuids::boot insteadof RevisionableTrait;
    }

     /**
    * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    public $incrementing = false;
    
    protected $table = 'paymentplans';
    
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

Customers Table:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\PaymentPlan;
use App\Models\PaidInFull;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\DeliveryMode;
use App\Models\Region;
use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;




class Customer extends Model
{
    use RevisionableTrait;
    use Uuids;

    use RevisionableTrait, Uuids {
        Uuids::boot insteadof RevisionableTrait;
    }
    
    /**
    * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    public $incrementing = false;
    
    protected $table = 'customers';

    protected $dontKeepRevisionOf = ['LastLogin'];

    public function paymentplans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentPlan::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we help you if we have no idea what your schema/models are, what those "a bunch of filters" are, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was related to UUID's - In laravel 8 I needed to declare in the Customer Model that the $keytype = string.  This is how I fixed it.

````
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\PaymentPlan;
use App\Models\PaidInFull;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\DeliveryMode;
use App\Models\Region;
use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;




class Customer extends Model
{
    use RevisionableTrait;
    use Uuids;

    use RevisionableTrait, Uuids {
        Uuids::boot insteadof RevisionableTrait;
    }
    
    /**
    * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $table = 'customers';
    public function paymentplans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentPlan::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
    ```
````